# Change ActionBar pressed elements overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I can't find the way to change the overlay color on ActionBar items when I press on them. I have minsdk = 11 and I can't use

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_</item>
```

because it works only from API 14.

I created a values-v14 folder with a style.xml file, and for devices >= v.14 works in this way:

not pressed:
[image: not pressed]
pressed:
[image]

But, how can I do the same for version >= 11 to < 14 ?

This is my style.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">


</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/brand_color</item>
</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">


    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

In this file I easily changed the ActionBar background color, but I can't figure out how to change the overlay color on pressed items. Can someone help me?

Comment: You mean you want another color for hole action bar when it is pressed? Or just for selected item?

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear, thanks for the reply @MisaghEmamverdi !

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can change the color of pressed items. Add the two `actionButtonStyle` items to your style in values and it should work on all versions (with app compat). Just replace `@drawable/selector` with your own drawable for action buttons.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
</style>
```

Example `@drawable/selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="#ddffffff" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks, in this way works fine, but the "home" button has the same pressed background color as before! Do you know also hot to change the hintTextColor for the searchView in the Action Bar (also for that in API >= 11 ). Thanks

Comment: @Luca122131 I've modified the code to work for the home button as well. It should also work for the overflow button. I don't know how to change the hint for searchView so you'll have to search elsewhere, sorry.